# multiple pages full-page-width table working with revtex

Tags: longtable, revtex, supertabular, xtab, ltxgrid

I am trying to figure out how to make a full page-width table, which continues over multiple pages in two column document. I got it working for the standard article, unfortunately the journal I want to publish in, requires revtex4-1. I've found some questions on that topic. Non of them, however, mentions revtex environment and not many answers are satisfying to be honest, when it comes to longtable* (probably not the way to go with two columns - document formatting crashes afterwards), xtabular* or supertabular*.

One more thing, can I get it working without page break afterwards?

My only working example without revtex unfortunately:

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}%
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\afterpage{\onecolumn
\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
\end{xtabular*}
\twocolumn
}
\lipsum[6-14] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem is that `revtex4-1` loads the `ltxgrid` package, which makes a number of changes to the latex kernel. In particular, the handling of multicolumn material is changed. The latex commands `\onecolumn` and `twocolumn` are replaced by `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid`.  In addition, `ltxgrid` modifies the `longtable` macro.

The `widetext` environment of `revtex4-1` packages the switch from two columns to one column so that single column material can be placed into an environment which begins and ends with leaders (or adornments). The adornments are intended to guide the reader across the column breaks.  This environment is mainly aimed at wide equations or passages of text that need visual emphasis, but you can also put a table into it.

You can also just use `onecolumngrid` and `twocolumngrid` directly, which may be preferred if you don't want the adornments around the table.

First, I'll illustrate with your MWE and `widetext`.  Then, I'll show a solution using `longtable` to continue the headers and footers across page breaks, without the adornments.

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}%
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]


\afterpage{\begin{widetext} %<===
\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll}
\hline\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Heading for a lengthy table}}\\
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
\hline\hline\hline
\end{xtabular*}
\end{widetext} %<===
}
\lipsum[6-14] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

The `widetext` environment adds the adornments automatically; and, because they are set as leaders, they will drop out at page breaks.  So, we see an adornment at the end of this table and not at the starting page break.

[image]

For the `longtable` case, I'll switch to using `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid`.  We want `longtable` to reach the full width of the page, so we again include `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.  Ordinary, we would also use

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
```

to remove the default `\fill` on either side of the table (see `longtable` documentation, page 7). However, `ltxgrid` has rewritten part of the macro, overriding these manual selections.  Instead, we can define another alignment option for `longtable`, analogous to the [c], [l], and [r] that are already defined.  I'll call this option [e] (i.e., we have extracolsep):

```
\def\LT@LR@e{\LTleft\z@   \LTright\z@}%
```

(I had thought that I would also need to use `xpatch` as follows, but it seems unnecessary in this case:

```
\xpatchcmd{\LT@array@longtable}{\if l#1\LTleft\z@ \LTright\fill}{\if e#1\LTleft\z@ \LTright\z@ \else\if l#1\LTleft\z@ \LTright\fill}{}{}
```

I'm not sure why this patch isn't also needed).

Putting all this together, we have the following code:

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}%
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\LT@LR@e{\LTleft\z@   \LTright\z@}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\afterpage{\onecolumngrid
\renewcommand{\doublerulesep}{0pt}
\begin{longtable}[e]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllll}
\hline\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Heading for a table}}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Heading for a table}}\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Con't next page\ldots}}\\
\endfoot
\hline\hline
\endlastfoot
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
\end{longtable}
\twocolumngrid
}
\lipsum[6-14] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, it may be of interest that this particular table will fit into a two column format (under `ltxgrid`) with `longtable` if you comment out `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid`.

Comment: I assume this also works with longtable?

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Seems to do so admirably.  I will add to the example to illustrate that.  See the `ltxgrid` documentation (Sect 5.2) for a discussion of compatibility.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much, I struggled with that for a while, that is just great!

Answer (score 0):

`revtex` defines the `table*`environment specifically for text-wide tables. Their typing is deferred to the following page:

```
\documentclass[aip, amsmath, amssymb, reprint]{revtex4-1}%
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table*}
\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 \\
\end{xtabular*}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[6-14] % more filler text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't table* only one page long?

Comment: @JohnKormylo. I didn't know, but I've just tested, you're right. I'll remove my answer in a moment.